# jquery address and preventing google analytics tracking?

Tags: google-analytics, jquery-address

How would I go about preventing the tracking of hash path changes within google analytics while using the jquery address plugin?

original URL:

```
/?watch
```

When moving sliders on the page, address bar is appended:

```
/?watch#/204;276
```

Within analytics I'm seeing it tracked as unique page views like so:

```
/?watch/204;276
```

I'm just wanting it to be tracked as:

```
/?watch
```

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [custom search and replace filter](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1034834&topic=1034830&ctx=topic) with a regular expression in the search string.

**Before setting up any filters, make a "master" profile in GA that contains unfiltered data.** That way if your filter affects your data negatively, you have all your data unfiltered and backed up.

The regular expression I used is `^/\?watch[/0-9;]+` You can test it at [RegExPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html). I didn't put the hash (#) symbol in the regex because, according to your question, GA is not tracking it in the request URI.

[image]